# About writing: From an economical point of view or from an economic point of view?

Tags: grammar, writing

Is it right to say in an opinion essay, *from an economic**al** point of view*? (with the final "al" in the word economical?)

Our English teacher claimed this to be wrong in class and that 70% of the students had this wrong in the essay. I wished to get this clarified from a native speaker because she insists that it is "economic" and not "economical"

Comment: ***Economic***  point of view! Economical means "cheap".

Comment: I guess both are technically possible. Can you please quote the longer passage in which this phrase appears, so we can have context to help you decide?

Comment: Nope, economic is right. Economical is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The right word to use here is **economic**.

> Economic is all about how money works, but something economical is a good deal. You might take an economic studiesclass to understand the ebb and flow of cash in the world, but if you buy a used textbook for it, you're being economical.

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/economic-economical/)